# Change the product tab position in magento 2.2.9

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, tabs, position

I am trying to swap two tabs around, Product Details and Specification. I want Specification tab to show up first and then Product Details tab.

I already did some research on stackExchange and add the After="" tag but its not working.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">SPECIFICATIONS</argument>
</arguments>
</block>

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" after="product.attributes" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
<argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
<argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
<argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
<argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3, they have added a sort-order to the tab block definitions that you set in layout XML. In the meantime, while continuing to use 2.2, you will have to do some custom code, as the "before" and "after" directives don't work for this. I recommend you reference this Inchoo blog post: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/customising-product-info-tabs-magento-2-part-2/

Comment: Thank you , I cannot find details.phtml under /Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view. My theme does not use "details.phtml" it has its own file called "attribute.phtml" however there is one details.phtml file but its under Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type I am not sure where should I place this code "   $detailedInfoGroup = ["reviews.tab", "product.info.description", "product.attributes"]"

Answer (score 0):

Use **priority** tag like below

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">REPLACE WITH SOME NUMBER</argument>
</arguments>
```

example code

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Where should I add this ? under catalog_product.xml ? then where should I place this code under ? container name="product.info.options.wrapper.common" label="Product Options" after="product.row.main.detail"/> or <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml">

Comment: Yes you need to update your themes's Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product.xml

and you can put above code after product.info.media container